# how to permanently allow sshd-keygen-wrapper in OSX even after reboot

Tags: macos, ssh, firewall

How do I make sshd-keygen-wrapper in OSX firewall settings sticky so it is always allowed after reboot?

I've seen a lot of questions answered about enabling ssh to OSX by allowing sshd-keygen-wrapper in firewall settings, but I have not seen anyone tell how to make it sticky.

Everytime I reboot, ssh-keygen-wrapper is disabled in firewall settings, so I have to manually allow it every single time. I'd like to avoid manual intervention after each reboot. I have OSX 10.13.3.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself eventually.

In the Firewall Options just below the list of services, just turn on the chek-mark for "Automatically allow built-in software to receive incoming connections".

I never imagined this meant that: make the permission sticky across reboot. How could anyone connect the dot between "Automatically" and "Make it sticky after reboot"? I originally thought it meant "Automatically allow ALL built-in software to receive incoming connections" so I never thought of opening the firewall that way. I don't know how "Automatic" it is to set it "sticky" when "manually" rebooting. Besides, non-built-in software settings had their permission sticky after reboot without having to set "Automatically allow downloaded signed software incoming connection" on, which compounded the confusion.